Linear gradient in d3
I'm trying to create a conic gradient effect using the D3.js library, but I understand that conic gradients aren't natively supported. My goal is to manually implement a clockwise gray gradient that moves along the rim of a circle, starting from the 12 o'clock position after the circle is rendered and finally turns the whole circle gray.

From the point of view of the application, it is important that the animation starts after the rendering is finished, and also that the gradient runs as described, similar to a curved progress bar.
In this example you can see my progress so far.
How can I achieve a smooth, continuous gradient that transitions clockwise around the circle?
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>D3 Circle Gradient</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<svg width="500" height="500"></svg>
<script>
const renderCircle = () => {

  const svg = d3.select("svg");
  svg.selectAll("*").remove();

  const margin = {
    top: 50,
    right: 50,
    bottom: 50,
    left: 50
  };

  const width = 500;
  const height = 500;
  const g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

  // Circle properties
  const cx = width / 2;
  const cy = height / 2;
  const radius = 0;
  const finalRadius = Math.min(width, height) / 4;
  const strokeWidth = 10;


  const gradientId = "linearGrad";
  const gradient = svg.append("defs")
    .append("linearGradient")
    .attr("id", gradientId)
    .attr("gradientUnits", "objectBoundingBox");


  gradient.append("stop")
    .attr("offset", "0%")
    .attr("stop-color", "red");

  gradient.append("stop")
    .attr("offset", "100%")
    .attr("stop-color", "gray");

  const circle = g.append("circle")
    .attr("cx", cx)
    .attr("cy", cy)
    .attr("r", radius)
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", `url(#${gradientId})`)
    .attr("stroke-width", strokeWidth)
    .transition()
    .duration(100)
    .attr("r", finalRadius)
    .on("end", function() {


      let angle = 0;
      let step = 1;

      d3.interval(() => {
        angle += step;
        if (angle <= 360) {
          gradient
            .attr("x1", `50%`)
            .attr("y1", `50%`)

            .attr("x2", `${50 + Math.round((Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180) * finalRadius)/(2*finalRadius / 100))}%`)
            .attr("y2", `${Math.round((finalRadius - Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180)*finalRadius)/(2 * finalRadius / 100))}%`);
        };
      }, 10);
    });

};

renderCircle();
</script>
</body>
</html>

Thank you!

You’re right that SVG doesn’t current have conic gradients, which is a huge bummer. But depending on what exactly you’re trying to do, you probably don’t need to use SVG at all.
It wasn’t totally clear what animation you wanted, so I left it out here, but hopefully this is enough to get you on the right path.


.circle {
    /* a circle with the given diameter */
    width: 200px;
    aspect-ratio: 1;
    border-radius: 50%;

    /* the border width is the thickness of the ring */
    border: 8px solid transparent;

    /* the conic gradient. adjust as needed. */
    background:
        conic-gradient(
            gray,
            red,
            gray
        ) border-box;

    /* a mask to punch out the middle of the circle, leaving only the ring */
    mask:
        linear-gradient(transparent, transparent) content-box,
        linear-gradient(white, white) border-box;
    mask-composite: intersect;
}
<div class="circle"></div>



D3 bills itself as a visualization library, but really it’s a DOM manipulation library that has a lot of utilities for visualization. In this case, D3 can happily interpolate a style declaration (like for background), which can help you do fancy things with the conic gradient.
(You could also do fancy things with the conic gradient using registered custom properties and CSS animations, but browser support may not be where you need it yet.)
